# Firebase Get All Auth Users taking Forever in cloudrun

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-run

We're trying to fetch 86k of our firebase users, **on local & firebase functions it takes 2 minutes for all**, but in cloud run it is taking on average **20 seconds *per call*** (you can only request 1k users per calls according to firebase docs).

Interestingly, get all firebase real time database uses takes 15s, but in cloud run it took 365s.

```
2022-06-17T00:03:04.986000061Zgrabbed users data from db, total: 86442 in 364.015s
2022-06-17T00:03:05.732000112ZProgress 1000 0.746s
2022-06-17T00:03:15.131999969ZProgress 2000 9.847s
2022-06-17T00:03:39.332999944ZProgress 3000 34.347s
2022-06-17T00:04:03.832999944ZProgress 4000 58.846s
2022-06-17T00:04:28.433000087ZProgress 5000 83.447s
2022-06-17T00:04:51.733000040ZProgress 6000 106.747s
2022-06-17T00:05:58.332000017ZProgress 7000 172.947s
```

**Any thoughts on how to solve this?** No special network settings in place on cloud run.

Background Info:
Cloud run instance is using NodeJS 14. 2GB Memory which stays at 8% usage. CPU usage stays around 10%. The user object is relatively small, but across all these users it's about 60-70 MB. In firebase functions, only 256 MB of memory are required to do the fetching.

PS: I've yet to test if region makes a difference, as cloud run is in us-east1 and functions are in us-central1. Will be testing soon.

Comment: Your question has no context on the problem, what the numbers are measuring, size of network transfers, CPU and memory utilization, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley Just updated, the CPU and memory wasn't notable so I didn't add that info, it shoudln't be the issue I figured. As for network transfer, I'm not sure how to measure that or how I would change that in CloudRun if that's the problem?

Comment: Regarding networking, how much data is transferred? Your question still has no details so that this problem can be analyzed or even duplicated.